# Slider Hide/Show Google Map Markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map that renders markers and one of the arrays I build within the markers is **arrTimeStamp** This captures an integer 0 - 24 representing the hour a user logged in.  The slider displays 0 - currentHour (which is the current time rounded to the hour).  What I wish to do is hide/show the markers based on their time stamp relative to the slider value.

Example if I have 10 markers logged in at 2pm and then 5 more at 3pm.  When the slider is on 3pm I should see all 15 markers on the map, but if I slide the slider to 2pm it should hide the 5 markers that are marked for 3pm, therefore only showing the 10 2pm markers.  If I slide the slider back to 3pm I see all 15 again.

I attempted to use .setMap(null) .setMap(map) for my hide and show but this returns an undefined error on .setMap.  If I only use .setMap(null) if works fine and hides them, but this is a one way street as I can not show them again without .setMap(map).  I have seen several articles relating to the problems surrounding .setMap in this regard but I have not found a solution.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
var d = new Date();
var currentHour = d.getHours()+1;

$( "#slider" ).slider({
  value: currentHour,
  min: 0,
  max: currentHour,
  step: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val(ui.value);
    var time = parseInt($('#amount').val());

    for(x = 0; x <= arrMarkers.length; x++){
        arrMarkers[x].setMap((arrTimeStamp[x] >= (currentHour - time)) ? null : map);
    }

  }
});
```

Here is all my code for the map and slider.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var arrMarkers = [];
var arrInfoWindows = [];
var arrTimeStamp = [];
var timeStamp = 0;
var marker = 0;
var numLocations = 0;

function mapInit()
{
    var centerCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100); // USA
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: centerCoord,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    var d = new Date();
    var currentHour = d.getHours()+1;
    $.getJSON("http://www.URL.com/superadmin/json/map-data.cfc?method=getFeedData&feedType=location&timespan=" + currentHour, {}, function(data)
    {

        $.each(data.DATA, function(i, item)
        {

            numLocations++;
            $('#locationsOnline').html(numLocations);

            // displays proper image for marker
            function markerinformation()
            {
                var markerImage = 'http://www.URL.com/css/images/map_property_green_pin.png';
                return markerImage;
            }

            markerTitle = item.LOCATIONNAME


            // creates the markers
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.LOCATIONLATITUDE, item.LOCATIONLONGITUDE),
                map: map,
                title: markerTitle,
                icon: markerinformation()
            });

            arrMarkers[i] = marker;

            // infowindow content
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            {
                content: "<p><b>Location:</b> " + item.LOCATIONNAME + "</p><p><b>Customer:</b> " + item.CUSTOMERNAME + "</p><p>" + item.LOCATIONCITY + ", " + item.LOCATIONSTATE + "</p>"
            });

            arrInfoWindows[i] = infowindow;

            // "live" bind click event
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
            {
                // this closes all open infowindows before opening the selected one
                for(x = 0; x < arrInfoWindows.length; x++)
                {
                    arrInfoWindows[x].close();
                }
                infowindow.open(map, marker); // open the clicked marker infowindow

            });

            arrTimeStamp[i] = item.TIMESTAMP;


        });
    });


}

$(function() {

mapInit(); // initialize map (create markers, infowindows, and list)
var d = new Date();
var currentHour = d.getHours()+1;

$( "#slider" ).slider({
  value: currentHour,
  min: 0,
  max: currentHour,
  step: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val(ui.value);
    var time = parseInt($('#amount').val());

    for(x = 0; x <= arrMarkers.length; x++){
        arrMarkers[x].setMap((arrTimeStamp[x] >= (currentHour - time)) ? null : map);
    }

  }
});

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: are you sure that map is accessible inside the function / is map defined globally?

Comment: I went ahead and pasted all the map code as well for reference.

Comment: What external javascript files are required? What HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(x = 0; x <= arrMarkers.length; x++){
```

JS arrays are zero-indexed,so you need to change this to:

```
for(x = 0; x < arrMarkers.length; x++){
```

e.g. if your array has 3 elements you want to loop three times (obviously).  So you want to reference

```
arrMarkers[0]
arrMarkers[1]
arrMarkers[2]
```

if you go up to x = arrMarkers.length, you'll be referring to arrMarkers[3], which doesn't exist.

Comment: That's unreal.  I can't believe that would hose up the entire system.  Thank you so much for your help.